# GEdit does not remember the "Text wrapping" setting

Tags: 17.10, gedit

On one of my 2 Ubuntu computers, GEdit does not remember the "Text wrapping" setting after closing the app.

Now I try to find the reason for that difference in behavior.

Both computers are equipped with Ubuntu 17.10 and received the latest updates.
One of them is German, the other one English. Remembering text wrapping does not work on the German computer, but I doubt that is the reason since the localization usually does not lead to any problems.

**Where can I find the settings file where GEdit stores its settings?**

[UPDATE]

As requested below, the output of `ls -la`:

```
eval@dv:~$ ls -la ~/.config/dconf/
total 72
drwxrwxr-x  2 eval eval  4096 Apr  4 18:33 .
drwx------ 40 eval eval  4096 Feb  3 19:53 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 eval eval 36456 Apr  4 18:33 user
-rw-rw-r--  1 eval eval 27894 Sep 17  2016 user.1V1ONY
```

(btw. what is that second user file? Looks a bit strange, almost like the output of a virus. It is on one of my 2 computers.)

Comment: When your are using gedit as root it never saves settings. Not sure if that is your case.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I agree.  The corruption is most likely caused by some other GUI application ran as sudo that stores gnome settings.

Answer (score 3):

**Gedit Preference:**

Gedit stores it's preferences in: `~/.config/dconf/user`

This is where many gnome applications store their settings.

Of course, the interface for this settings is in Gedit itself.  That's the steps you're already using since your question made references to being remembered in one of your computers.

You can use the commandline interface to access these settings with the **gsettings` command.

There are a number of gedit wrap-modes.  You can check one with this command:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor wrap-mode
```

The output would either be: `'word'` or `none`.

**Fixing problems with settings being remembered:**

As far as the problem you're having with it being remembered, this is usually the result of having run a gui that made some gnome settings changes from elevated access (i.e. `sudo [gui command`] with gui command being many of the available gui desktop applications).

Some of the files in your personal space has become owned by a different user than you.  You can find out which files or folders in your personal space has this problem by running this:

```
$ time find ~/ -mount ! -user $(whoami)
```

You can fix the problem files by running a variation of this command:

```
 $ sudo chown $(whoami):$(whoami) [filename]
```

That would be the resolution of a file.

When I experience the problem I resolve the issue by regaining a ownership of all the files in my personal space, since for the integrity of my system, I always use my computer as a normal user, and only use `sudo` when I want to make a systemwide change, which I wouldn't be doing in my personal space.

```
$ time sudo chown -R $(whoami):$(whoami) ~/
```

Comment: Thank you. I can change it using `gsettings set` but unfortunately the checkbox in the editor still does not write to `~/.config/dconf/user`. It only seems to read that file. Of course I am not working with `sudo`. The account is not even in the `sudoers` file.

Comment: But now I tested it again on the second computer and it seems to show the same behavior. No write to that file.

Comment: @user22611 Will you add the output of `ls -la ~/.config/dconf/` to your question?

Comment: I just added the output.

Comment: @user22611 Your output appears to be properly owned.  I can help to investigate what is happening.  It might take a few messages.  I can go over some of the details in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75518/gedit-problem) if have time.  I'll put the steps there and you can respond when it's convenient.

Comment: @user22611 By the updated information in your question, the content of your output is being saved.  There's something else involved that is also making changes to your gnome settings.  It's apparent from the modification date of your `~/.config/dconf/user` file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75526/discussion-between-l-d-james-and-user22611).